# Validation rule to be adjusted

Tags: validation-rule, profile, contact, isblank

Hello after adjustment of validation rule when I am creating contact with one of the profiles from the validation rule and insert mobile phone the validation rule still doesn't allow me to create a contact. What should be changed here?:

```
AND(
    OR(
        $Profile.Name = "Barnes MS - Standard User New",
        $Profile.Name = "Barnes MS - CDA User",
        $Profile.Name = "Barnes MS - External Sales Agent",
        $Profile.Name = "Barnes MS - Marketing User"
    ),
    OR(
        ISBLANK(MobilePhone),
        ISBLANK( Phone )
    ),
    NOT( $User.bgi_Bypass_Validation_Rules__c)
)
```

Comment: The formula you've provided contains syntax errors, so it'll be hard for people to help you until you fix that. You can [edit] your question to make changes.

Comment: Hello, I edited it. Thank you for the comment

Answer (score 1):

Validation rules will stop editing if they equal TRUE. Your current statement will trigger a validation error if either Phone or Mobile Phone is blank and one of those profiles is making the edit. If only one field will suffice you can change your

`OR( ISBLANK(MobilePhone), ISBLANK( Phone ) )`

to

`AND( ISBLANK(MobilePhone), ISBLANK( Phone ) )`

This requires both to be blank to fire the validation.

Comment: Thank you very much @Brian Biddiscombe. I am new here so can I vote on your answer somehow or how reward you?

Comment: @user88574 you should take the site [tour]. The general Stackexchange culture is to upvote (when you have enough reputation) good answers, and mark one as "accepted" after your problem has been resolved. Accepting an answer gives both you and the answerer reputation points, signals to the community that the question doesn't need any more attention, and signals to others that the solution is likely to be good/correct.